# Finding argument in complex numbers

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I am having troubles with finding the argument in complex numbers(except for the obvious ones).

Is there an easy or algorithmic way to find the argument? Does anyone have a mnemonic to find them?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Computation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\tan(\arg(a + b i)) = b/a$$ should do the trick. No mnenmonic, just draw the number in the complex plane and mark the angle you need.

For the obvious ones:

- Real numbers have $b=0$, meaning the argument $\phi$ must be a number for which $\tan(\phi)=0$. This leaves the candidates $\phi = 0$ and $\phi = \pi$, depending on whether the number is positive or negative
- For imaginary numbers, $a=0$, leaving the candidates of $\phi = \pi/2$ or $\phi = -\pi/2$.
- For any other number, say, $1+i$, you have $\tan(\phi) = 1$, leaving you with $\phi = \frac{\pi}{4}$ or $\phi = \frac{5\pi}{4}$. Since the number is in the first quadrant, $\phi = \frac{\pi}{4}$ is the right answer

Comment: Could you use this formula in an example?